# How to express amount of combinations as coefficient of an exponent in a product of polynomials?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

How many ways are there of distributing 20 desserts among 10 people so that no person gets more than 5 desserts? Express the amount as coefficient of an exponent of a product of polynomials or series and calculate it.

I am struggling to understand how am I supposed to solve this problem in the way the wording suggests.

Normally I would just solve it with the formula for distributing $n$ items among $r$ groups and PIE like this:

$${{29}\choose{9}}-{{10}\choose{1}}{{23}\choose{9}}+{{10}\choose{2}}{{17}\choose{9}}-{{10}\choose{3}}{{11}\choose{9}}$$

where the second combination number is amount of combinations where at least one person has 6 or more desserts, third is where at least two people have 6 or more, and the fourth one is where three people have 6 or more.

How can I express that in the way the problem wording asks for?

Comment: Hint: consider the polynomial $1+x+x^2+\dotsb+x^5$. This (the exponents) represents what a single person can get. Now you have to do this for all $10$ people. Then look for coefficient of $x^{20}$.

Comment: This is called a generating function approach.  It is very useful and the term is a good place to start the search.